# enlarge axes limits by fixed distance

Tags: pgfplots

According to pgfplots manual it is possible to enlarge axes limits using `enlarge x limits` and `enlarge y limits` properties.  One can specify relative and absolute values, but they are in units of the axes.  Is it possible, to enlarge limits by some fixed distance, e.g. `1cm`?

If possible, I would need a solution, that could be defined in the `.style` property, as I would like **all** my plots to have axes extended by the same value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such feature in any version of pgfplots up to and including 1.6.1 .

However, there are plans to include it for the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Should I add it to Feature Requests?  What is an approximate interval between two releases?

Comment: Yes, you should. Since the current stable 1.6.1 has been released last week, it might be some time. Typically half a year... but there are always "unstable" versions at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/ for which an installation is relatively easy. The feature might be ready within the next weeks. Take a look at that link; it also contains a brief history indicating what has been added to the unstable.

Comment: Thanks.  I shall keep watching and install unstable version with the feature as soon as it will be available.